# Open source optical lattice clock

Tags: popularity-contest, graphical-output

A recent [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38076/how-to-plot-a-figure-like-this) showed how Mathematica could be used to make a beautiful optical lattice clock image.  The image looks like this.

[image]

This challenge is to reproduce this image as closely as possible using as short code as possible using only easily available open source tools (and without just downloading the image or parts of it).

**Rules** As it is not reasonable to ask for a pixel by pixel reproduction this is a popularity contest. However, please up-vote code that is a short (in the style of code-golf) and which produces an accurate and beautiful reproduction of the image.

Comment: Wow. It's been ages since I've last used POVray. Time to refresh my memory, I guess :-)

Comment: @downvoter: why don't you like this challenge?

Comment: Maybe because they just don't like it? Maybe because OP says it's a popularity contest and then tells the populus what to do? Maybe using random open source libraries is a somewhat unclear restriction? Maybe because they don't think that image is beautiful and can't agree with the fundamental statement of the question? Maybe because it's not well formatted? (To name a few reasons.)

Comment: I had no idea what this was about, so here's the original article. http://www.nature.com/nphoton/journal/v5/n4/covers/index.html I thought maybe we had to arrange the green balls into digits. But apparently this is not the case, they are just atoms confined in potential wells by laser beams that therefore move in a determined way to tell the time. So if you did arrange them into digits, they would be the smallest in the world.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### [POV-Ray](http://www.povray.org/), 512 characters

Here's my try. I didn't manage to replicate the lighting, so I've decided to keep the variation of highlight positions rather than to put the lights further away to keep the background brighter.

The area shadow is rather low-quality. I might as well turn it off completely (and save precious characters), but if someone is willing to donate some computing power and crank up the shadow quality and/or the dither quality, I'll gladly accept.

```
#include"functions.inc"       
camera{location<-3,5,-6>right x look_at 0 focal_point 0 aperture 1 blur_samples 9}  
#macro s(p)sphere{pi*p+y/3 1 pigment{rgb<2,8,2>/9}finish{phong .5 phong_size 5 specular 1 roughness .001}}#end
#macro l(p,c)light_source{p c/8 area_light 9*x,9*z,3,3}#end l(<6,6,0>,<8,4,8>)l(<0,6,0>,<4,8,8>)
isosurface{function{y/3+pow(cos(x)*cos(z),2)/2}contained_by{box{-9,100}}pigment{tiling 1 color_map{[.9 rgb 1][1 rgb 0]}scale .5/pi}}   
s(0)s(<0,0,-1>)s(<-1,0,0>)s(<0,0,2>)s(<2,0,1>)s(<2,0,3>)
```

#### Result:

[image: 1]

#### ungolfed:

```
#version 3.7;
#include "functions.inc"                
global_settings{assumed_gamma 1} 
camera{
  location <-3,5,-6>  
  right x //set the aspect ratio
  look_at 0   
  focal_point 0 aperture 1 blur_samples 9
}  

#macro l(p,c) // position, color
  light_source{
    p c/8 
    area_light 9*x,9*z,3,3
  }
#end 
l(<6,6,0>,<8,4,8>)
l(<0,6,0>,<4,8,8>) 

isosurface{
  function{y/3+pow(cos(x)*cos(z),2)/2}
  contained_by{box{-9,100}}
  pigment{
    tiling 1
    color_map{[.9 rgb 1][1 rgb 0]}       
    scale .5/pi
  } 
}            
#macro s(p) //position
  sphere{
    pi*p+y/3 1
    pigment{rgb<2,8,2>/9}
    //phong for the wide highlights, specular for the small ones.
    finish{phong .5 phong_size 5 specular 1 roughness .001}
  }
#end   
s(0)
s(<0,0,-1>)
s(<-1,0,0>)                       
s(<0,0,2>)    
s(<2,0,1>) 
s(<2,0,3>)
```

P.S.: I've only counted the five line-breaks to round the character count to a perfectly round number.

Comment: Is it possible to get more of it in focus?

Comment: @Lembik reducing the aperture will enlarge the region in focus. I will try some lower values soon, but a full render takes a while.

Comment: I get a Parsing error and a Parsing warning. They are "Possible Parse Error: assumed_gamma not specified in this POV-Ray 3.7 or later
 scene. Future versions of POV-Ray may consider this a fatal error. To avoid
 this warning, explicitly specify 'assumed_gamma 1.0' in the global_settings
 section. See the documentation for more details.
" and "Parse Warning: This scene had other declarations preceding the first #version
 directive. Please be aware that as of POV-Ray 3.7, unless already specified via
 an INI option, a #version is expected as the first declaration in a scene file."

Comment: @Lembik they are just warnings. I can add `assumed_gamma` and `#version`, but code golf was never about clean coding as far as I'm aware, was it?

Comment: It certainly wasn't :) (But it would be nice in any case for the ungolfed version.) I am trying it with aperture 0.5 now.

Comment: Added to the ungolfed version. The ungolfed version is without warnings now.

Comment: It actually doesn't take long at all to render on my computer. Are there any changes you would like to borrow some cpu cycles to test out?  How do you increase the shadow quality and/or the dither quality?

Comment: @Lembik you can increase the shadow quality by increasing the `3,3` (amount of source points in each direction) in the light definition. You can then add `adaptive n` to it, where `n` is the amount of recursion (`9,9 adaptive 3` starts at 2x2 points, `9,9 adaptive 2` starts at 3x3 points).

Comment: The FOV quality is improved by increasing the amount of `blur_samples` or by antialiasing (`+a0.3` in the render, where `0.3` is how much a pixel needs to differ from its neighbors before it's anti-aliased).

Comment: How about http://imgur.com/9ueRjra ?  I used  aperture 0.8 and 9,9 adaptive 3 .

Comment: @Lembik that looks better indeed!